# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have a special case here...
In my code, the jQuery is initialised and also `$(...).on('click', function() {})` is working fine.
But when I am trying to use `.addClass` function I am getting that error message.

code:

```
<script>
   $('#subservice-@subservice.Id').on('click', function () {
   console.log('service @subservice.Name clicked');
   $('#subservice-@subservice.Id').addClass('bg-success');
   });
</script>
```

So, everything is working, but `.addClass` function. Ideas?

I tried different versions of jQuery, but no success.

Comment: I assume you have some pre-processing happening that replaces that invalid ID with a valid one? Please show us what the browser actually sees, not the the code that gets pre-processed.

Comment: If you're using an unaltered jQuery library and `$` refers to that unaltered jQuery library, I can't see any way this would happen. jQuery doesn't conditionally remove `addClass` from its objects. Perhaps you're using something customized? Or even something that isn't jQuery at all, but supports the `on` method in a similar way to jQuery?

Comment: Side note: In jQuery code, I'd usually use `$(this).addClass(/*...*/);` inside that event handler, though it shouldn't matter with an ID selector as there should only be a single element matched anyway...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! The id selector is not a problem as the .on function is working -> I am getting console output when clicked. However, I actually sort it out just now with this modification --> I wrapped my jquery in $(function($) {}) and everything is ok now... strange, but it is working. Thank you again...

Comment: Not strange, I was writing an answer as you were commenting. Your solution is similar to mine, though yours delays your code slightly.

Comment: I should clarify my first comment above: That ID **selector** is invalid. The **ID** is valid (there are no rules for ID values other than that they can't be duplicated or blank, and cannot contain whitespace.) The selector only works because jQuery optimizes `$("#xyz")` into a call to `document.getElementById`, and since `getElementById` doesn't use a CSS selector, it doesn't matter that the ID selector is invalid. But still, it is, and if you did something like `$("#subservice-@subservice.Id span")`, that would fail, because it would skip the optimization. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - interesting. I am on thinking that there is nothing wrong as this JavaScript is used within razor pages and `@subservice.Id` is fetched from C# backend... Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: That's what I meant by pre-processing in my first comment. In the actual page delivered to the browser, is the selector as shown above, or something else?

Comment: the value of Id is always "subservice-xyz" where xyz is the Id number fetched from backend. So, I will get something like `$('#subservice-12')...` After the jQuery fix all is working as expected.

Comment: Great, that's a valid ID selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one way I can imagine this happening if you're using an unmodified jQuery: If you load something *else* that takes over the `$` symbol *after* the event handler is hooked up. Here's an example using PrototypeJS:

```css
.x {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click me</div>

<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Your code -->
<script>
$("#target").on("click", function() {
    $("#target").addClass("x");
});
</script>

<!-- Load PrototypeJS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js"></script>
```

If that's what's happening, ideally consider using only jQuery **or** the other library on the page, not both. But if you can't do that (or at least, not right now), you can wrap your code in a function that ensures `$` refers to jQuery:

```css
.x {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click me</div>

<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Your code -->
<script>
(function($) {
    $("#target").on("click", function() {
        $("#target").addClass("x");
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

<!-- Load PrototypeJS -- doesn't mess things up -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how the function accepts a parameter called `$`, and we call it supplying `jQuery` as the argument for that parameter. Then it doesn't matter what the global `$` refers to, the one in that code refers to jQuery.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I think I might have some additional libraries used in the project and `(function($) {})` is sorting the problem out.